# How can I perform a running sum on a list using only functional methods?

Tags: python, functional-programming

Say we start with:

```
x = list(range(10))
```

I'd like to process `x` to get a list of running sums like:

```
[0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: can't seem to figure out an elegant way to do it :/ -- looked at some answers but nothing that caught my fancy

Comment: mmm I see in the questions cited above: cumsum = lambda X: X[:1] + cumsum([X[0]+X[1]] + X[2:]) if X[1:] else X

Comment: let me try that out